# Upload photo does not work in server

Tags: php, image-uploading

The code works well in my localhost(xampp) and this is edit part for my web page. But when I put on my server, the upload photo function does not work(does not upload image to server). Any help would be much appreciated. Below is my code for upload photo.

```
define ("MAX_SIZE","1000"); 
 $errors=0;
$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
if ($image == "")
{
    $uploadmsg = '<br /><font color=red>'.ERR_BLANK_IMAGE_FIELD.'</font>';
    $errors=1;
}
if ($image) 
{
    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $extension = base_getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);
    if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
    {
        $uploadmsg = '<br /><font color=red>'.ERR_UNKNOW_IMAGE_EXTENTION.'</font>';
        $errors=1;
    }
    else
    {
         $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
        {
            $uploadmsg = '<br /><font color=red>'.ERR_EXCEEDED_SIZE.'</font>';
            $errors=1;
        }
        $newname="images/eitem_".$itemPart.".".$extension;
        if($photo != "images/eitem_item_default.png")
        {
            $delete = unlink($photo);
        }
        else
        {
            $delete=1;
        }
        $copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
        if (!$copied || !$delete) 
        {                   
            $uploadmsg = '<br /><font color=red>'.ERR_IMAGE_UPLOAD_UNSUCCESS.'</font>';
            $errors=1;  
        }
    }
     if(isset($_POST['save']) && !$errors) 
     {
        $uploadmsg = "<br /><font color=red>".MSG_IMAGE_UPLOAD_SUCCESS."</font>";                   
        eitem_editItemPhoto($cid,$newname);                 
        eitem_editItem($cid,$itemPart,$shortDesc,$longDesc,$categoryList,$brandList,$packDetails,$minOrder,$supplier,$price);
     }
}
else
{
    eitem_editItem($cid,$itemPart,$shortDesc,$longDesc,$categoryList,$brandList,$packDetails,$minOrder,$supplier,$price);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="cell bottomBorder" style="width:170px; height:170px;vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;padding:5px;">
    <img src="../eitem/<?php echo $photo; ?>" id="imge_path" style="height:150px; width:120px"/>
</div>
<div class="cell bottomBorder" style="vertical-align:middle;">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
    <div>(150px x 120px)</div>
        <?php echo $uploadmsg; ?><br />
        <span class="note">Please use an image with .png,.jpg or .gif file format.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** 
I could not get the value of `$copied` in this line `$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);` when I'm trying to echo out the value in server. But it works in my localhost

Comment: Check the folder Permissions in Server

Comment: Could be a lot of issues happening here. The path to the uploadfolder could be invalid, uploading could be disabled via php.ini, The file might be to big, The folderpermissions might be invalid, etc... Without any errormessage there is not much we can do.

Comment: Can you are your upload form in the description ?

Comment: @SiddhuSiddharthaRoy: The other modules of uploading image works well except for this one. 
AgeDeO: The other upload image function works well but only this does not work.

Comment: I could not get the value of `$copied` in this line `if (!$copied || !$delete) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probbably you don't have perrimisions for forders in host, you need to give folder permission 755 on linux and create if folder not exists.

Comment: Thanks fico! I'm fairly new to this. Your answer help me to solve it.